# Deployment error - The AppMenu called 'AppSwitcher' is standard and cannot be deleted on pushing to scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, scratch-org, app

I am trying to do a simple push of my vscode to my scratch org using `sfdx force:source:push -u  test-zqrn4ol3ypft@example.com` and I run into this error

| Type | Project Path | Problem |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Error | force-app\main\default\appMenus\AppSwitcher.appMenu-meta.xml | The AppMenu called 'AppSwitcher' is standard and cannot be deleted |

In my directory, I don't have the appMenus folder at all. I can't figure out why this problem is showing up and what does the error message actually mean

[image: DirectoryScreenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes there's quirks with the *standard* metadata types - it's expecting it to be in your source as every org has two [AppMenu](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5dqAAC) files (`AppSwitcher.appMenu` & `Salesforce1.appMenu`). Since it's not there, it seems it attempts to delete it (which isn't possible).

You'll either want to do one of the following

- Retrieve the `AppMenu` metadata from your source org into your repository
- Exclude `AppMenu` in your `.forceignore` file for source commands so it ignores this metadata type in CLI source commands.

**I'd recommend ignoring it** as it doesn't add any value in your source - there's [issues](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5dqAAC) deploying it as such to re-order app menu items and users can easily customize the order of apps that display in the app launcher in Lightning anyway.

[image]

You can see an example of this being done in the [lwc-recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/.forceignore) repository for certain standard metadata which includes appMenus

```
# Standard metadata
package.xml
**/appMenus/**
**/appSwitcher/**
**/objectTranslations/**
**/profiles/**
**/settings/**

# LWC configuration files
**/jsconfig.json
**/.eslintrc.json

# LWC Jest
**/__tests__/**
```

Comment: I was of the understanding that the deployments that we do are never destructive. I've followed that principle whenever deploying things like profiles as it prevents removal of any existing configuration. However that has always been with ANT & metadata API. Do the SFDX source deployments work differently or it is only this specific type that behaves in this manner where an attempt to delete is made if is is not present in the source ?

Comment: AppMenu is unique. However, `force:source:push` syncs changes from your local project to your org and is different than a deployment with ANT specifying exactly what to deploy. With `force:source:push` being a sync -  if you delete a file in VS Code (ex. apex class, layout, etc) and run the command - it will sync those changes which would be a destructive action. `force:source:deploy` is the other command closer to what you might be used to with ANT. Profiles are their own world, but the same rules apply across tools as it's all the metadata API behavior.